# JQuery distinct between smartphones, tablet or computers with different sizes but the same $(window).width()

Tags: jquery, width, device-orientation

I got a problem I would like to solve trying to differentiate between different devices.

The point is I have 3 different devices to test my code:

```
- Moto G (3rd gen) (Smartphone):
    - Width screen: 6'3 cm
    - Height screen: 11 cm
    - Resolution: 720 x 1280
- Huawei T1-701w (Small tablet):
    - Width screen: 9 cm and
    - Height screen: 15'3 cm
    - Resolution: 600 x 1200
- Samsung sm-t580 (Big Tablet):
    - Width screen: 13'8 cm
    - Height screen : 21'9 cm
    - Resolution: 800 x 1280
```

I measured with my hands the cm of width and height and searched it in internet in the specifications from each device the resolution in px of the screen.

But all 3 devices in the browsers have the same width in pixels (980 px in the vertical orientation that I get from "alert($(window).width());"). So I can't distinct between an smartphone and the rest of devices.

Obviously the three devices have a clearly different size and I would like to apply different rules of css for each one but I can't find a solution.

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "I measured with my hands"   comedy. You could  maybe use the user agent string to differentiate them. People say 'data-useragent' in css is hacky, but it seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You will have to use innerWidth instead of width property for that purpose.

```
    $window.innerWidth
```

or try this

```
    $window.screen.width
```

Comment: It gets the same width than $(window).width(). Again 980 px width

Comment: window.screen.width is the answer thank you. The results now with this property are 360, 600 and 800 and I can distinct between them.

Comment: pleasure dude we are here to help each other